# Why is my function failing to trim whitespace on one URL, but working fine on another?

Tags: function, go, whitespace

I have a Dataset Struct, which looks like this -

```
type Dataset struct {
            Publications      []GeneralDetails `bson:"publications,omitempty"           json:"publications,omitempty"`
            URI               string           `bson:"uri,omitempty"                    json:"uri,omitempty"`
    }
```

And a GeneralDetails struct, which looks like this -

```
type GeneralDetails struct {
    Description string `bson:"description,omitempty"    json:"description,omitempty"`
    HRef        string `bson:"href,omitempty"           json:"href,omitempty"`
    Title       string `bson:"title,omitempty"          json:"title,omitempty"`
}
```

I have a ValidateDastaset funciton which trims whitespace and returns a parsed URL -

```
func ValidateDataset(ctx context.Context, dataset *Dataset) error {
    var generalDetails = &GeneralDetails{}
    var invalidFields []string
    if dataset.URI != "" {
        dataset.URI = strings.TrimSpace(dataset.URI)
        _, err := url.Parse(dataset.URI)
        if err != nil {
            invalidFields = append(invalidFields, "URI")
            log.Event(ctx, "error parsing URI", log.ERROR, log.Error(err))
        }
    }

    if dataset.Publications != nil {
        generalDetails.HRef = strings.TrimSpace(generalDetails.HRef)
        _, err := url.Parse(generalDetails.HRef)
        if err != nil {
            invalidFields = append(invalidFields, "href")
            log.Event(ctx, "error parsing URI", log.ERROR, log.Error(err))
        }
    }

    if invalidFields != nil {
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid fields: %v", invalidFields)
    }
    return nil

}
```

However, the whitespace is only being trimmed on dataset.URI, but not on generalDetails.HRef and I really don't understand why. Is anyone able to help please?

Edit: here's what's in my test package, which is how I know the whitespace isn't being trimmed -

```
var testPublications = GeneralDetails{
    Description: "some publication description",
    HRef:        "http://localhost:22000//datasets/publications",
    Title:       "some publication title",
}

func createDataset() Dataset {
    return Dataset{
        ID:  "123",
        URI: "http://localhost:22000/datasets/123",
        Publications: []GeneralDetails{
            {Description: "some publication description"},
            {HRef: "http://localhost:22000//datasets/publications"},
            {Title: "some publication title"},
        },
    }
    }

}

func createGeneralDetails() GeneralDetails {
    return testPublications

}
```

And the actual test itself, which is failing -

```golang
Convey("Successful validation (true) returned", t, func() {

        Convey("when generalDetails.Href contains whitespace it should not return an error ", func() {
            dataset := createDataset()
            dataset.ID = "123"
            generalDetails := createGeneralDetails()
            generalDetails.HRef = "  http://localhost:22000//datasets/publications  "
            validationErr := ValidateDataset(testContext, &dataset)
            So(validationErr, ShouldBeNil)
            So(generalDetails.HRef, ShouldEqual, "http://localhost:22000//datasets/publications")
        })
    })
```

Comment: Maybe it is not whitespace? Print the data as a []byte and see

Comment: We'd need to see a sample of the data that's being mishandled. From the code, the only things I could guess is either it's not true whitespace as Burak suggested, or the `dataset.Publications` is `nil` so that block isn't being executed at all.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added test details if that is more of a help?

Comment: You sre not adding general details to your dataset.

Comment: @mihai I've updated to add general details to the dataset (I did try this earlier), but it doesn't make a difference. Still not trimming the whitespace

Answer (score 3):

In the function `ValidateDataset`, you created a

```golang
var generalDetails = &GeneralDetails{}
```

But you never assign to this variable, or iterate the `Publications` field of the passed in `*Dataset`

```golang
if dataset.Publications != nil {
    generalDetails.HRef = strings.TrimSpace(generalDetails.HRef)
    _, err := url.Parse(generalDetails.HRef)
    if err != nil {
         invalidFields = append(invalidFields, "href")
         log.Event(ctx, "error parsing URI", log.ERROR, log.Error(err))
    }
}
```

You're just editing the nil `generalDetails` var, and forgetting completely about `dataset.Publications`.

You'd need to do something like

```golang
for i := range dataset.Publications {
    generalDetails = &dataset.Publications[i]
    // validate
}
```